# Django url tag multiple parameters

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have two similar codes. The first one works as expected.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       (r'^(?P<n1>\d)/test/', test),
                       (r'', test2),
{% url testapp.views.test n1=5 %}
```

But adding the second parameter makes the result return empty string.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                           (r'^(?P<n1>\d)/test(?P<n2>\d)/', test),
                           (r'', test2),)


{% url testapp.views.test n1=5, n2=2 %}
```

Views signature:

```
def test(request, n1, n2=1):
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try

```
{% url testapp.views.test n1=5,n2=2 %}
```

without the space between the arguments

**Update:**
As of [Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#url) (and maybe earlier) the correct way is to omit the comma and separate arguments using spaces:

```
{% url testapp.views.test n1=5 n2=2 %}
```

Comment: Is there any documentations available for this feature in Django Docs?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an actual example of me using this technique. Maybe this will help:

```
{% if stories %}
  <h2>Stories by @{{author.username}}</h2>
  <ul>
    {% for story in stories %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'reader:story' author.username story.slug %}">{{story.title}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% else %}
  <p>@{{author.username}} hasn't published any stories yet.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url

From Django 1.5 Warning Don’t forget to put quotes around the function path or pattern name!

```
{% url 'some-url-name' arg1=v1 arg2=v2 %}
```